# Determine resolution of a display on a remote systyem?

Tags: linux, monitors

How can I determine the resolution of a display on a remote system. If I use `xrandr` it displays the resolution
of my local screen:

```
me@rome:~$ ssh -X road
me@road's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 17.10 (GNU/Linux 4.13.0-16-generic i686)
me@road:~$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 370mm x 230mm
   1440x900      59.89*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: That’s not that easy, since the remote system might well have several displays, or no display at all. I’d suggest reading `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (or wherever your distro puts this log file), but the way it is printed might be driver-dependent…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh into your server then export your local display (`echo $DISPLAY`):

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Then run `xrandr`

or simply run

```
DISPLAY=:0 xrandr
```

Comment: Assuming you've connected as the same user logged into `:0`, of course.